# Convert Eclipse JDT ITypeBinding to a Type

Tags: java, eclipse, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I'm looking for a general way to convert an `org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ITypeBinding` instance to an `org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.Type` instance.  Although I feel there should be some API call to do this, I cannot locate one.

There appear to be various ways to do this manually depending on the specific type.

Is there any general way to take an `ITypeBinding` and get a `Type` without all of these special cases?  Taking a `String` and returning a `Type` would also be acceptable.

**Update**

From the response so far, it appears I do have to handle all these special cases.  Here is a first attempt at doing so.  I'm sure this is not completely correct so scrutiny is appreciated:

```java
public static Type typeFromBinding(AST ast, ITypeBinding typeBinding) {
    if( ast == null ) 
        throw new NullPointerException("ast is null");
    if( typeBinding == null )
        throw new NullPointerException("typeBinding is null");

    if( typeBinding.isPrimitive() ) {
        return ast.newPrimitiveType(
            PrimitiveType.toCode(typeBinding.getName()));
    }

    if( typeBinding.isCapture() ) {
        ITypeBinding wildCard = typeBinding.getWildcard();
        WildcardType capType = ast.newWildcardType();
        ITypeBinding bound = wildCard.getBound();
        if( bound != null ) {
            capType.setBound(typeFromBinding(ast, bound)),
                wildCard.isUpperbound());
        }
        return capType;
    }

    if( typeBinding.isArray() ) {
        Type elType = typeFromBinding(ast, typeBinding.getElementType());
        return ast.newArrayType(elType, typeBinding.getDimensions());
    }

    if( typeBinding.isParameterizedType() ) {
        ParameterizedType type = ast.newParameterizedType(
            typeFromBinding(ast, typeBinding.getErasure()));

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Type> newTypeArgs = type.typeArguments();
        for( ITypeBinding typeArg : typeBinding.getTypeArguments() ) {
            newTypeArgs.add(typeFromBinding(ast, typeArg));
        }

        return type;
    }

    // simple or raw type
    String qualName = typeBinding.getQualifiedName();
    if( "".equals(qualName) ) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No name for type binding.");
    }
    return ast.newSimpleType(ast.newName(qualName));
}
```

Comment: There's a small bug:  
  
    _capType.setBound(typeFromBinding(ast, **wildCard.getBound()**), wildCard.isUpperbound());_

If the typeBinding is a raw collection, wildCard.getBound() will return null and the method will fail to produce a type for a valid situation. You just need to check the bound and not set it to fix the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just found an alternative solution which might be preferable. You could use [org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.rewrite.ImportRewrite](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/rewrite/ImportRewrite.html), which manages import statements of a compilation unit. Using Type addImport(ITypeBinding,AST), you can create a new Type node taking existing imports into account and adding new ones if necessary.

Comment: Because I was affected by this: ImportRewrite has the requirement "The AST has to be created from an ICompilationUnit, that means ASTParser.setSource(ICompilationUnit) has been used when creating the AST".

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to do with the 'Type' object or why you need it.

- If you need say the declaring node for the TypeBinding i.e. an existing Type node - you can use http://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/FAQ#From_an_IBinding_to_its_declaring_ASTNode
- However, if you need a new ASTNode to be used to modify source via ASTRewrite then you have to hand-craft it yourself and handle all the cases. Note that you do not need to handle all subtypes of 'Type' in all situations, e.g. UnionType (Java 7) is only relevant in catch blocks.

Comment: I do need it for `ASTRewrite`, where I want to capture the expression result into a new variable via inline assignment without altering the type of the expression.

Comment: I updated the question with potential code for handling the cases.  Can you suggest any cases I've missed?

Comment: From a quick glance looks ok to me.